# install doxygen on wsl got Could NOT find Iconv (missing: ICONV_COMPILES)

Tags: ubuntu, cmake, windows-subsystem-for-linux, doxygen

I tried to install doxygen on wsl, ubuntu 20.04 LTS,

Follow https://www.doxygen.nl/download.html,
in `cmake -G "Unix Makefiles" ..`, I got

```
CMake Error at /home/user/intel/oneapi/intelpython/python3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cmake/data/share/cmake-3.21/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:230 (message):
  Could NOT find Iconv (missing: ICONV_COMPILES)
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /home/user/intel/oneapi/intelpython/python3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cmake/data/share/cmake-3.21/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:594 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
  cmake/FindIconv.cmake:87 (find_package_handle_standard_args)
  CMakeLists.txt:124 (find_package)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

I tried `sudo apt-get Iconv`, leads to `E: Invalid operation Iconv`. Here https://github.com/doxygen/doxygen/issues/6248, some one sugguests `pkg search libiconv`, but I am not sure if `pkg` is for ubuntu.

Comment: The `missing: ICONV_COMPILES` in the error message means that [code in the given quotes](https://github.com/doxygen/doxygen/blob/master/cmake/FindIconv.cmake#L80) has been failed to compile or link. The code can be represented with two lines: `#include <iconv.h>` and `int main() { iconv(iconv_t(-1), 0, 0, 0, 0);}`. You could try to compile that code manually: paste it into file `test.cpp` and run `g++ test.cpp`. If that compilation succeed, then try to clean build directory and run `cmake` again.

Comment: thanks. later I found `sudo apt install doxygen` works for me.

Comment: Be aware that this might be a bit an older doxygen version (current version is 1.9.2), for the latest snapshot you can have a look at https://github.com/doxygen/doxygen/actions the latest master build and from this, at the bottom, the artifacts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sudo apt install doxygen` works.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to build doxygen from source and install it on WSL2 or Ubuntu, first make sure that the required tools are installed.

- `flex -V && bison -V && iconv -V && make -v && cmake -version && python3 -V`

Normally, `flex`, `bison`, `libiconv`, `make`, `make`, and `python` are pre-installed with WSL2 or Ubuntu. So, no need to install any of them again.

For my case, I installed `libiconv` in `usr/local/bin`, but `libiconv` was already installed in `usr/bin`. So, I was getting the error: **Could NOT find Iconv (missing: ICONV_COMPILES)**.